# Using MultiValueField and MultiWidget in Django Admin Form for a range

Tags: python-3.7, django-2.1

First off, I am using Python 3.7 on Windows and Django 2.1.3.

I am attempting to store a range of numbers in a CharField in a django table. I also want the admin site to display two number text boxes side by side to denote the lower value limit and the upper value limit respectively. I have the following files and django code:

**car/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

# Create your models here.


class Car(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'car'
        db_table = 'cars'
        verbose_name_plural = 'cars'

    make = models.CharField(_('manufacturer'), max_length=32)
    model = models.CharField(_('model'), max_length=24)
    msrp = models.CharField(_('suggested price'), max_length=11)
```

**car/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import ModelForm, MultiWidget, MultiValueField, NumberInput, IntegerField
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator, ValidationError

# Register your models here.
from .models import Car


class RangeWidget(MultiWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.widgets = [NumberInput(), NumberInput()]
        super().__init__(self.widgets, *args, **kwargs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            return value.split('/')
        return ['', '']

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        datalist = [
            widget.value_from_datadict(
                data, files, '{name}_{i}'.format(name=name, i=i)
            ) for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets)
        ]
        try:
            v = '/'.join(datalist)
        except ValueError:
            return ''
        else:
            return v


class RangeField(MultiValueField):
    widget = RangeWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        error_messages = {
            'incomplete': 'Enter two numbers',
        }
        fields = (
            IntegerField(
                error_messages={
                    'incomplete': 'Enter a number between 1 and 99999.'
                },
                validators=[
                    MinValueValidator(limit_value=1, message='Field cannot be less than 1'),
                    MaxValueValidator(limit_value=999999, message='Field cannot be greater than 99999')
                ],
                required=True
            ),
            IntegerField(
                error_messages={
                    'incomplete': 'Enter a number between 1 and 99999 that is equal or greater than the lower limit.'
                },
                validators=[
                    MinValueValidator(limit_value=1, message='Field cannot be less than 1'),
                    MaxValueValidator(limit_value=999999, message='Field cannot be greater than 99999')
                ],
                required=True
            )
        )

        super().__init__(
            error_messages=error_messages,
            fields=fields,
            require_all_fields=True,
            **kwargs
        )

    def compress(self, data_list):
        return '/'.join(data_list)


class CarChangeForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['msrp'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'range', 'min': 1, 'max': 99999})

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ['make', 'model']
        exclude = []
        widgets = {
            'msrp': RangeWidget
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        try:
            lower, higher = cleaned_data.get('msrp').split('-')
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            raise ValidationError(message='Provide both msrp values')

        if lower.isdigit() and higher.isdigit() and int(lower) > int(higher):
            self.add_error(
                'msrp',
                'The lower MSRP cannot be more than higher MSRP.'
            )
        else:
            cleaned_data['msrp_lower'] = lower
            cleaned_data['msrp_higher'] = higher
            return cleaned_data


class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = [
        ('make', 'model',),
        'msrp',
    ]

    form = CarChangeForm

    list_display = ('make', 'model', 'msrp')


admin.site.register(Car, CarAdmin)
```

It seems like everything works alright, except that the validators that I've specified under RangeField.fields do not validate the form and I am allowed to enter negative numbers and leave fields blank. Why isn't django respecting or running the validators that I've added to these fields? The one validation that DOES work is the one I've done in the custome clean() method where I make sure that the lower limit is not greater than the upper limit.

Answer (score 1):

adding `msrp = RangeField()` to the CarChangeForm solved the problem. Django doesn't automatically initialize a Field for your column. You have to do it yourself in the form.